# Please configure a GWT SDK?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I have just installed the Google App Engine Plugin for eclipse and want to create a new project. But i only get:

[image]

Why cannot I create a new project?

greetings and thx in advance

Comment: Not sure if you want to use GWT or not - it seems like you did not install GWT with the plugins - if you do not want to use GWT just uncheck the Google Web Toolkit checkbox on this dialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plugin is not same as the SDK. Plugin just makes it easy to work with GWT projects. 
The actual GWT compiler and libraries are present in the SDK which needs to be downloaded separately.
Once you download and extract the SDK, You have to configure its location in Eclipse's Preferences. Go to `Window > Preferences > Google > Web Toolkit` and add the SDK there.

Comment: do you see the SDK location configured in `Preferences`?

Comment: when I want to reinstall the google web development toolkit I get that: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Web Toolkit SDK 2.4.0

Comment: I guess you are trying to install the SDK through eclipse Software Update feature. Download the .zip from the website using your browser. Unzip it and configure that path in GWT preferences.

Comment: I have the same problem, because I couldn't find a seperate SDK to download. Googles page says "Plugins nad SDKs", but there is only the plugin.

Comment: The "SDK only" link is at the bottom of the page. Direct link: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.4.0.zip

Comment: Hi, I am also getting the same problem. I externally downloaded sdk and added the same into window --> preferences --> google --> google web toolkit. But, Still it is showing SDK not installed in eclipse console.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

If you do not want to use GWT just uncheck the "Use Google Web Toolkit" checkbox on that same dialog. You do not need this turned on in order to create a New Web Application Project.

I personally think it was confusing that the checkbox for GWT is turned on by default, even if you don't have one installed.

The SDK that you installed with your eclipse plugin should be sufficient.